# Replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with empty strings

Tags: java, regex, non-alphanumeric

I tried using this but didn't work-

```
return value.replaceAll("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "");
```

Comment: Guys, you forget there are alphabets other than the Latin one.

Comment: But if you want to validate a hostname for instance this would be good to exclude invalid alphabets.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Use `[^A-Za-z0-9]`.

Note: removed the space since that is not typically considered alphanumeric.

Comment: Neither should the space at the end of the character class.

Comment: the reg exp is ok, just remove "/" from the regexp string 
from value.replaceAll("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "");
to value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");

you don't need the "/" inside the regexp, I think you've confused with javascript patterns

Comment: note that this onl works with Latin alphabet and doesn't works with accent characters or any "special" char set.

Answer (score 149):

Try

```
return value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

or

```
return value.replaceAll("[\\W]|_", "");
```

Comment: With underscores, `return value.replaceAll("\\W", "");`

Comment: Of course. Compilers are great at spotting that sort of thing.

Comment: The second one doesn't answer the question. What about characters like : / \ etc?

Answer (score 92):

You should be aware that `[^a-zA-Z]` will replace characters not being itself in the character range A-Z/a-z. That means special characters like `é`, `ß` etc. or cyrillic characters and such will be removed.

If the replacement of these characters is not wanted use pre-defined character classes  instead:

```
 str.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]", "");
```

PS: `\p{Alnum}` does not achieve this effect, it acts the same as `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post - it was very useful to me. Additionally, I believe this is the actual answer to the question. The Latin alphabet isn't the only one in the world!

Comment: Actually, the stated regex will treat "^" as a valid character, since only the first occurrence of "^" is negating the meaning of the selection. `[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]` works well.

Comment: @JakubTurcovsky https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html defines IsAlphabetic and IsDigit as binary properties. Alpha and Digit are POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only). Except the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag is specified.

Comment: @AndreSteingress Correct, the reason `{IsDigit}` doesn't work for me and `{Digit}` does is that I'm trying this on Android. And Android has `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` turned on by default. Thanks for clearance.

Comment: How to only allow Alpha, Digit, and Emoji?

Answer (score 65):

```
return value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```

This will *leave* spaces intact. I assume that's what you want. Otherwise, remove the space from the regex.

Answer (score 23):

You could also try this simpler regex:

```
 str = str.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}", "");
```

Comment: Or, preserving whitespace: `str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}\\s]", "")`

Comment: Or `\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}`.

Answer (score 13):

## Solution:

`value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")`

## Explanation:

> `[^abc]`
> When a caret `^` appears as the first character inside square brackets, it negates the pattern. This pattern matches any character except a or b or c.

Looking at the keyword as two function:

- `[(Pattern)] = match(Pattern)`
- `[^(Pattern)] = notMatch(Pattern)`

Moreover regarding a pattern:

- `A-Z = all characters included from A to Z`
- `a-z = all characters included from a to z`
- `0=9 = all characters included from 0 to 9`

Therefore it will substitute all the char NOT included in the pattern

Answer (score 12):

Java's regular expressions don't require you to put a forward-slash (`/`) or any other delimiter around the regex, as opposed to other languages like Perl, for example.

Answer (score 8):

I made this method for creating filenames:

```
public static String safeChar(String input)
{
    char[] allowed = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_".toCharArray();
    char[] charArray = input.toString().toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : charArray)
    {
        for (char a : allowed)
        {
            if(c==a) result.append(a);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty brute-force. Regex is the way to go with the OP's situation.

Comment: You're right, regex is better. But at the time, regex and me I didn't come along well.

Comment: Hah, does anyone really get along that well with regex? ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to also allow alphanumeric characters which don't belong to the ascii characters set, like for instance german umlaut's, you can consider using the following solution:

```
 String value = "your value";

 // this could be placed as a static final constant, so the compiling is only done once
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\w]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

 value = pattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
```

Please note that the usage of the UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag could have an impose on performance penalty (see javadoc of this flag)

Answer (score 1):

Simple method:

```
public boolean isBlank(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("null") || value.trim().equals(""));
}

public String normalizeOnlyLettersNumbers(String str) {
    if (!isBlank(str)) {
        return str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = " Chlamydia_spp. IgG, IgM & IgA Abs (8006) ";

    System.out.println(value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""));

}
```

output: **ChlamydiasppIgGIgMIgAAbs8006**

Github: https://github.com/AlbinViju/Learning/blob/master/StripNonAlphaNumericFromString.java

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava you can easily combine different type of criteria. For your specific solution you can use:

```
value = CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9')
        .or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
        .or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'))).retainFrom(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [CharMatcher](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) provides a concise solution:

```
output = CharMatcher.javaLetterOrDigit().retainFrom(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dart

If you tried this and it didn't work..

> value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

Just use RegExp like this:

> value.replaceAll(RegExp("[^A-Za-z0-9]"), "");