# java: how to normalize text?

Tags: java

I want to build index for my program and one of the most important step is to normalize text.
e.g. I need to convert "[(Mac Pro @apple)]" to "macproapple", in which I filter blank space, punctuations([()]) and special chars(@). My code is like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
sb = filterPunctuations(sb);
sb = filterSpecialChars(sb);
sb = filterBlankSpace(sb);
sb = toLower(sb);
```

Because this will generate a lot of String objects, I decide to use StringBuilder. But I don't know how to do it with StringBuffer. Does any one has some suggestions? I also need to handle chinese characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805518/replacing-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-empty-strings

Comment: but stringBuffer doesn't have the replaceAll method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `replaceAll` api with a regular expression

```
String originalText = "[(Mac Pro @apple)]";
String removedString = originalText.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]", "").toLowerCase();
```

Internally `replaceAll` method uses StringBuffer so you need not worry on multiple objects created in memory.

Here is code for `replaceAll` in `Matcher` class

```
 public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
        reset();
        boolean result = find();
        if (result) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            do {
                appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
                result = find();
            } while (result);
            appendTail(sb);
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I decide to use string replaceall method.

Comment: If string object allocations worry you, then you should precompile the regular expression!

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
class Solution
{
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
                String s = "[(Mac Pro @apple)]";
                s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
                System.out.println(s);
        }
}
```

This gives the output of

```
MacProapple
```

A small explanation for above lines is-

`s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")` removes everything in the string that is not(denoted by ^) in A-Z and a-z. Regex in Java is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

If you want to convert the string to lowercase at the end, you need to use `s.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: thank you,I think I would use String if I can't find a solution for using StringBuffer

Comment: You're wrong. In Java a String object is immutable. Each time you change a String (for example replaceAll()), a new String object is created.