# remove all special characters in java

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805518/replacing-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-empty-strings)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class io{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String c;
if((c=scan.nextLine())!=null)
 {
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher match= pt.matcher(c);
    while(match.find()){
         c=c.replace(Character.toString(c.charAt(match.start())),"");
         }
    System.out.println(c);
      }
   }
}
```

**Case 1**

```
Input : hjdg$h&jk8^i0ssh6
Expect : hjdghjk8i0ssh6
Output : hjdgh&jk8^issh6
```

**Case 2**

```
Input : hjdgh&jk8i0ssh6
Expect : hjdghjk8i0ssh6
Output : hjdghjk8i0ssh6
```

**Case 3**

```
Input : hjdgh&j&k8i0ssh6
Expect : hjdghjk8i0ssh6
Output : hjdghjki0ssh6
```

Anyone please help me to figure out, what is wrong in my code logic ??

Comment: Consider looking at the Java naming conventions and format your source code before you submit the question.

Comment: Try `[^a-z$]|[^A-Z$]|[^0-9$]`

Comment: @paranoid-android actually, i wrote the above code on notepad.. :(

Comment: @var___ why would you write code in notepad?

Comment: That looks.. like a really complicated way of doing it. `String s = "hjdg$h&jk8^i0ssh6"; System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")`

Comment: Just because it's in Notepad doesn't mean you can't indent with Tab. :p

Comment: @paranoid-android I tried my best.

Comment: @var___ No worries man, just being difficult. As long as your tried to that's fine. :)

Comment: If you want valid chars, like ç, à and ã use .replaceAll("[!@#$%ˆ&*/\\(\\)\\{\\};:<>/?,.|\\[\\]]", "");

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `[\\W+]` or `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"` as regex to match any special characters and also use String.replaceAll(regex, String) to replace the spl charecter with an empty string. remember as the first arg of String.replaceAll is a regex you have to escape it with a backslash to treat em as a literal charcter.

```
          String c= "hjdg$h&jk8^i0ssh6";
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher match= pt.matcher(c);
        while(match.find())
        {
            String s= match.group();
        c=c.replaceAll("\\"+s, "");
        }
        System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: `c=c.replace(match.group(), "");` this one also working . Why ??

Comment: @var___ note that i used replaceAll which takes first args as regex, while you are using replace whihc doesn't take regex, thus it works .. :)

Comment: ok.. i got it now.. thanks !!

Comment: same question, better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4283366/637609

Comment: This also replaces all white spaces. So, will not be a good idea to apply it on a sentence.

Answer (score 18):

You can read the lines and replace all special characters safely this way. 
Keep in mind that if you use `\\W` you will not replace underscores.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use `regex` package.

Comment: Well if it's for an assignment and you HAVE to use `regex` package, then you may be looking at an unnecessarily complex solution. Why do you want to use the `regex` package?

Comment: So, that i can learn more about `regex` package

Comment: In that case `GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR`'s answer is probably the best?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that the indices returned by `match.start()` correspond to the position of the character as it appeared in the original string when you matched it; however, as you rewrite the string `c` every time, these indices become incorrect.

The best approach to solve this is to use `replaceAll`, for example:

```
        System.out.println(c.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
```