# How to get only symbols and numbers from file on Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for some way to get easily only words and numbers, without any type of weird symbol like `("'/&%$·...` so I get from a code:

```
int i=0;
```

This: int, i, 0.

Any good function for Java?

Comment: What all stuff you want to eliminate from file?

Comment: from a file? a regex line by line

Comment: I want eliminate from a file(or a string) everything that is not special characters like, only get A-Z, a-z and 0-9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove all special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361556/remove-all-special-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, you have to get line by line and replace non alphanumerical characters by an empty, then rewrite your line again, to replace all non alphanumerical characters you can use :

```
line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s]", "")
```

The regex mean, replace all non (`^`) alphabetic (`a-zA-Z`) or digit (`\d`) or space (`\s`).

You can use something like this :

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {//read the line
    putData = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d]", "");//replace all non alphanumerical 
    ....
    bw.write(putData);//write it again
}
```

Comment: Sorry what is bw? Can I use [^A-Za-z0-9]?

Comment: it is `BufferedWriter bw` @JavierBertoméuMuñoz this was just an example you have to get the idea, this is the goal

Comment: yes you can use `[^A-Za-z0-9]` i thought you need the not replace the spaces, for that i put `\s` in the regex @JavierBertoméuMuñoz

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line and apply regex on each line.  To exclude certain characters ( <, >, %, $, /, \ etc.), you can make a regular expression like this:

```
[<>%\$=&@]
```

You can add more in this list. Now,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[<>%\$%@]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(unsafeInputString);
if (m.matches())
{
    // Invalid input: reject it, or remove/change the offending characters.
}
else
{
    // Valid input.
}
```