# How to remove "" from the string in java?

Tags: java

```
        [![While executing a command i am getting output with "" how can I supress those symbol in my output][1]][1]


          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgZDI.png


//OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
                out.write(3); // send CTRL-C
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("exit1");
                if (expect.expect("$") > -1) {
                    System.out.println("finding $");

                    contt = (expect.before);
                    if (contt != null && contt != "") {
                       output=contt.replaceAll("", " ");
                        System.out.println("afterline"+output);


                    } else {
                        contt="Error in Top Check";
                        System.out.println("Error in Top check");
                    }
//I am trying to replaceAll this string.
```

//I am running command though jsch and getting the following output which i have shared as screenshot.I need to display itby removing the"  " from the output.
            Need help in it

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Hint: String.replace(), Character.isISOControl(c) )

Comment: i have tried using repalce All.no psoitive result

Comment: SHOW us the code of what you've tried - that would improve your question a lot and would show efforts on your part - so we don't point into things you've already tried. (the "EDIT" button is your friend!)

Comment: Try to improve your questions, or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I think you are having some troubles with the replaceAll and the quotes. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string

Comment: output=contt.replaceAll("", " "); -> Replace nothing with something? Do you know that replaceAll needs a regex to work? You may want to take your response and iterate through all characters to see which ones are displayed bad

Comment: I am not being a dumbass to replace ""  with "". The "/" is not being shown up here.Thats y i was trying atttach a screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove all special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361556/remove-all-special-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Two plausible solutions:

1) Using standard replaceAll() method of String Class, eg :

```
String a = a.replaceAll("\"","");
```

2) Using Apache StringUtils replace method eg :

```
String a = StringUtils.replace(a,"\"",""");
```

Comment: it's not really " that's the problem but some unprintable characters in response