# How to remove all special characters from a string in java?

Tags: java

I want to remove all special characters from a string,i tried many options which were given in stackoverflow, but none of them work for me.

here is my code :

```
public class convert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {    
            List<List<String>> outerList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("11-","2")));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("(2^","1")));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<String>(asList("11","3)")));    

            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<outerList.size();i++){    
                    for(j=0;j<outerList.get(0).size();j++){    
                            outerList.get(i).get(j).replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");
                            if(outerList.get(i).get(j).matches("-?\\d+"){
                               continue;
                            }else{
                               System.out.println("special characters not removed");
                               System.exit(0);
                            }
                   }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the special characters? Not alphanumeric ones? Command ones? That of in range [32..255] - ASCII nut not command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (simple) error is that `s.replaceAll(...)` does not change `s` but yields a new changed string:

```
String s = outerList.get(i).get(j).replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");
outerList.get(i).set(j, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

in the case of not alphanumeric you can use

```
String value = "hello@() world";
value = value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(value) // => helloworld
```

something similar has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805518/replacing-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-empty-strings)

Comment: Note that you can use `\p{Alnum}` instead of `A-Za-z0-9`.

Comment: @AnoopDobhal Don't forget that `String` are immutable, so you have to assign the value back to the `String`: `value = value.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: @Enermis : OP don;t want examples like you provide, he want the hint / answer that in his code where he's wrong..

Answer (score -3):

Use `StringUtils` at Apache Commons Lang (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: Which method does this?

Comment: I think that the author of the post forgot to mention the use the method stripAccents of StringUtils