# Trimming multiple characters in a string

Tags: java, string

My program reads some strings from file which have to be post processed. The original text in the file looks like

```
A1DY^
BLKSS^
"GH67^"^
```

Where `^` is the space character I used to demonstrate. As you can see all words in the file end with space. Some words are in double quote. I want to store these strings in my program

```
A1DY
BLKSS
GH67
```

In other words, I want to trim all spaces and double quotes. If I use `str.trim();` it will remove the last space. So, the third line will be `"GH67^"`. I also used `str.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");` to trim the double quotes. The result is `GH67^`. That means, I have to trim it again.

Is there any better way to remove all spaces and double quotes at once? Note that I don't want to extract alphanumeric characters. I want to trim special characters.

Comment: Will this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805518/replacing-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-empty-strings

Comment: That extracts alphanumeric. If I have `DS-DK^` in the file I want to save `DS-DK`.

Comment: Using '\0' instead of spaces might be more useful, since '\0' is never used as a character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will trim any number of quotes or spaces from the beginning or end of your string:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^[ \"]+|[ \"]+$", "");
```

Comment: To prevent common newbie mistake, add `str =` in front.

Comment: Technically, removing leading spaces is counter to OPs requirements, but it likely makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas Where are you seeing that?

Comment: OP said *"As you can see all words in the file **end with** space"*. Sure, OP also tried to use `trim()`, which trims from both ends, but doesn't mean that using `trim()` would have been right, but since OP didn't think `trim()` would be wrong, there will probably never be leading spaces that needs to be retained, which is why I said *"it likely makes no difference"*, and I left my up-vote in place.

Answer (score 0):

In a strict interpretation of your question description, you only want *trailing* spaces removed, not leading spaces and not other whitespace characters like tabs (`\t`).

Also, a strict trimming function will only remove double-quotes if both a leading and a trailing pair is found, and only one such set.

If double-quotes are present, trailing spaces inside the double-quotes should also be removed.

To accomplish all that, **strictly**, in a single regex operation, do this:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^(\"?)(.*?) *\\1 *$", "$2");
```

This regex uses the `^` and `$` anchors to ensure it only matches against the entire string.

The leading `"` is optional, and matched as capture group 1, if present. The trailing `"` is only matched if leading `"` was matched, and leading `"` is only matched if trailing `"` is matched. This is done using a `\1` backreference to the optional leading `"`. If matched, they will be removed from the result.

No leading spaces are removed, but any trailing spaces before and/or after the optional trailing `"` are removed.

Anything not removed is captured in group 2, and retained in the replacement string.