# how can i find out words from string that contain special char

Tags: java, string

How can i find out words from a string that contain special char
Ex:

```
String sqlQuery="INSERT INTO TABLE(ID) VALUES(#ABC_11#),(#ABCDE_12#)";
```

o/p:

```
ABC_11
ABCDE_12
```

Comment: Are you looking for a java solution or mysql?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you kindly be more specific with your question so we can help you better? What do you mean by special character, for example?

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805518/replacing-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-empty-strings

Comment: special char means  any thing for example :

Comment: String sqlQuery="INSERT INTO TABLE(ID) VALUES(#ABC_11#),(#ABCDE_12#)";

Comment: # is the special char.

Comment: No :    from String "INSERT INTO TABLE(ID) VALUES(#ABC_11#),(#ABCDE_12#)";   find out # values like ABC_11 & ABCDE_12

Comment: Looks like you're trying to manually insert parameters in your SQL query. That makes you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Learn about "parameterized queries" and use those instead!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String sqlQuery="INSERT INTO TABLE(ID) VALUES(#ABC_11#),(#ABCDE_12#)";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#").matcher(sqlQuery);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll("#",""));
        }
```

Output

```
ABC_11
ABCDE_12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your input names first.
This might help you:

```
//your dirty name inputs
String dirty_name = "#ABC_11#"

//removes special characters like [~!@#$%^&*()-=+]
String name = dirty_name.replace('[^\w]','')

//put in your query
String sqlQuery="INSERT INTO TABLE(ID) VALUES("+name+")"
```